# Left Kan extension: switching K and F

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, functors

If $F:  ⟶ $ and $K:  ⟶ ℰ$ are functors, where $$ is small and both $$ and $ℰ$ are cocomplete. How do the left Kan extension of $F$ along $K$ (${\rm Lan}_K(F)$) and the left Kan extension of $K$ along $F$ (${\rm Lan}_F(K)$) relate with one another? (Is it safe to say that they are adjoints for example?)

EDIT: Actually, I asked the question in general but what I had in mind was the special case where $K := y:  ⟶ \widehat{}$ is the Yoneda embedding, so any tip to show that ${\rm Lan}_y(F) ⊣ {\rm Lan}_F(y)$ (or that ${\rm Lan}_F(y) \cong N_F := Hom(F(-), -)$) would be helpful as well.

Any insight on this would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $y : A \to[A°,Set]$ is the Yoneda embedding it is a general fact that, given a functor $f : A \to B$, there is the adjunction
$$
Lan_yf \dashv Lan_fy
$$ this is called [nerve-realization paradigm](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nerve+and+realization).

As you can see e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252383/the-kan-construction-profunctors-and-kan-extensions), asking that the two functors $F,K$ are related in this way is a rather strong request (in fact, the tentative proof in the answer contains a flaw, and to this day no convincing example, different than Yoneda extensions, has been given)

Comment: Thank you! That was the special case I had in mind when I wrote the question actually (I have edited it): do you know any nice proof of $Lan_yf \dashv Lan_fy$ (avoiding if possible too much co/end fu (as in the answer you pointed out))?

Comment: Or even better: a proof of ${\rm Lan}_F(y) \cong N_F := Hom(F(-), -)$

Comment: @Cooke4 The latter is easy: the category of elements of $\operatorname{Hom}(F(-),D)$ is precisely the comma category $(F\downarrow D)$ for any $D \in \mathcal D$. Hence the formula computing the pointwise left Kan extensions together with the Yoneda lemma (or mor precisely the density of the Yoneda embedding, which is a consequence) gives you the result.

Comment: You have to prove that $Nat(\hom(F,1),G)\cong Nat(y, GF)$; this can even be done directly! :-)

Comment: @FoscoLoregian The answer of Pece leads to a pretty straightforward result, but I can't figure out how to show that $Nat(\hom(F,1),G)\cong Nat(y, GF)$, since it is supposed to be natural in $G$ if I'm not wrong: any hint? :-)

Comment: By the Yoneda lemma applied to both sides, either a natural transformation $y\to GF$ or a natural transformation $\hom(F,1)\to G$ is equal to a family of maps $\{G(a,Fa)\mid a\in A\}$ such that...

Comment: @FoscoLoregian I'm really sorry, there must be something I'm missing but I don't see it: I can't even make sense of $G(a, Fa)$...